# Don't should we avoid internet acronyms/abbreviations/slang words?

Tags: discussion

I'm not a native english speaker, and frequently on this lovely and very good/useful site I see acronyms on questions, answers and comments. Everytime it happens I have to google the thing to understand what the people is saying. I think that avoid them is a good thing to make worldwide participation easier; and I want to know if an edition for changing only that seems good to this community.

Examples: AFAIK, AIUI, OTOH, ROT, FWIW, YMMV, 'tl;dr', DWHAHB, RDWHAHB, AAMOF...

Comment: I am a native English speaker and I have to google some of them as well.  But there are a few acronyms that need to stay e.g. O.G., S.G., F.G., PBW...etc.

Comment: Thanks to saying something! This question is more than a month old without no opinions! I agree with you, some of them need to be, or could be good. But I think it's restricted to homebrew/brewing world. 'Online forum talk' acronyms I think don't help at all.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that certain "internet" language is very confusing, but it is unfortunately something that we have to live with... to a degree.

I have edited questions/answers and removed/replaced strange abbreviations (like the ones that you mentioned).

But, as @jsolarski mention, there are certain abbreviations that are part of the hobby and they will remain.

Comment: afaict it's as good as part of the language now so should be considered common knowledge or searchable if not.